# Is 'reproof' [verb] a valid word? What does it mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I got this sentence from Swan's book:

> I must get my jacket cleaned. I'd better have my raincoat **reproofed**.

I assume the word reproofed is a past participle of **reproof**, judging by its structure and pattern of its vowels and consonants. I've been searching this word on website, but haven't found a single mention about it. Is it really a word?

Although, it's available on some well-known dictionaries such as [Collin](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/reproof), [Cambridge](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/reproof), [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reproof#examples), [Dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/reproof), and [Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/reproof?q=Reproof), it is a noun they provide. Those dictionaries are only my best resources when I don't know the meaning of a word. Do you know what does that word mean? Is it commonly used?

Comment: For future reference when you find a puzzling verb starting re try looking up the word minus re and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, in this context, it's "re + proofed" rather than "reproof + ed".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reproof (noun) means 'an expression of blame or disapproval'. The verb is 'reprove' (to deliver such an expression to someone).

To 'reproof' or 're-proof' a waterproof item (e.g. a tent, coat, etc) is to **re**-apply a water**proof** coating or treatment that was previously present but which has become old or worn and no longer keeps out the rain. You can buy a can or bottle of the substance or take the item to be re-proofed to the kind of shop that does dry-cleaning. The term is commonly used.

> re-proof (riːˈpruːf) vb (tr)
>
> 1. (Clothing & Fashion) to treat (a coat, jacket, etc) so as to renew its texture, waterproof qualities, etc

[Re-proof (The Free Dictionary)](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/re-proof)

Comment: Sometimes you put a coat in the washing machine on a cold wash cycle and use the special liquid instead of detergent.  Usually it smells quite unpleasant.